# PayPal Integration on BrainTree (On Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, paypal, xamarin.forms, braintree

I'm trying to implement braintree using drop in UI in xamarin.forms. By doing so I created a dependency service to use the respective code for iOS or Android. Starting out with the android implementation, I started with getting a package of bindings that allow me to call the functions in Android v2 SDK. Everything seem to work except for PayPal Integration.
[BrainTree android binding](https://github.com/NAXAM/braintreedropin-android-binding)

attempting to click on the paypal button will not result in any activity appearing and onActivityResult gets called with a first user result code with the exception

```
Com.Braintreepayments.Api.Exceptions.BraintreeException: BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity missing, incorrectly configured in AndroidManifest.xml or another app defines the same browser switch url as this app. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/android/v2#browser-switch for the correct configuration
```

Not being able to debug into why I got the exception I was able to emulate the checks - `isManifestValid`

Within `isManifestValid` I was able to retrieve the `ActivityInfo` for `BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity`
and it only returned false because `AppHelper.isIntentAvailable(fragment.getApplicationContext(), intent)` is false

[isManifestValid can be found here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/866210e4036462fc0b59839f431a4e43056541f1/Braintree/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/PayPal.java#L683)

Within `isIntentAvailable` `context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` returned an empty list making me think that the Intent is not registered to use any activity despite having declared the URL scheme in my AndroidManifest file.
[isIntentAvailable can be found here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/44e20eed28af498e980202f9f12579911be6e249/Core/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/internal/AppHelper.java#L13)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.3.16" package="com.company.abcmobileapp.android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="24">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:label="ABC" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:largeHeap="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
    <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.company.abcmobileapp.android.braintree" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ShareActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Is there any suggestions as to what I can do to further debug or fix the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact?_ga=2.3942901.436147500.1517590900-1868041817.1513354075&_gac=1.175260182.1514392694.EAIaIQobChMIpdjIsNCq2AIVF_5kCh04TA4eEAAYASAAEgJSEfD_BwE).</sub>

The formatting of your manifest file is in line with [our documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2#browser-switch-setup). You should set up a breakpoint within the [isIntentAvailable()](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/blob/44e20eed28af498e980202f9f12579911be6e249/Core/src/main/java/com/braintreepayments/api/internal/AppHelper.java#L13) method to inspect the `activities` object to see what other app/ activity is registered to handle the given `Intent`.

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return activities != null && activities.size() == 1;
}
```

You may have another version/build of your app installed that listens for the same URL scheme or manifest merging may have somehow ended up declaring it twice, which would cause this error.

Comment: Hi Lairen, thanks for your suggestion. I did attempt to step through the process but the `activities` object returned from `isIntentAvailable()` is an empty list.

Comment: Can you check to see if `com.company.abcmobileapp.android` is the package name and remove any capital letters or underscores if there are any in the package name?

Comment: Yep I have checked that too. I have also tried `${applicationId}.braintree` in place of `com.company.abcmobileapp.android.braintree` for the scheme. Both methods still resulted in the same exception.

Comment: Testing on and actual device actually worked. Testing on a colleagues' simulator also works which was very odd to me. I still can't figure out why it isn't working on my simulator and its working on pretty much everything else.